# $http in loop, wait the results

Tags: angularjs, synchronization, promise, http-post

I have this :

```
var j = 0;

// myList.length = 3
while(j < self.myList.length - 1){

    $http.post('myURL', self.myList[j].code).then(
            function(response){

                self.myList[j].plop = response.data;

            }, function(){

                // error

            }
        ).then(
            function(){
                // with this j++, my web page is freezing
                // j++;
            }
        );

    // with this j++, only the 3rd element of myList have a "plop" element
    //j++;
}
```

My problem is in comments :) for "j++".
If I remove the loop while and hardcoded the 3 step, it's working. But I don't know how to solve the issue with a loop. Do you have an idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Synchronized solution according to OP's comment:

```
var promises = [];
for(var i=0;i<self.myList.length;i++)
 promises.push($http.post(...));
$q.all(promises).then(function(results){
 //All results available here
 var data = results.map(result => result.data);
 data.forEach((e, idx) => self.myList[idx] = e);
})
.catch(function(e){
 //Handle error
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Issue is

1. `$http.post().then(function(){}, function(){})` is asynchronous function. So `.then()` method will be executed when loop is completed. This is the reason it always takes last value of j that is 2.
2. `then()` will come only one time with `$http.post()` so remove second `.then()`

Solution posted below:

```
var j = 0;
var i = 0;

// myList.length = 3
while(j < self.myList.length - 1){
    $http.post('myURL', self.myList[j].code).then(function(response){
                self.myList[i].plop = response.data;
                i++;

            }, function(){
                // error
            }
        );
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works better but not completely. In fact, $post are executed in parallel. So, the var "i" are not synchronized.